# Sul plurale dei nomi composti

Tags: word-usage, nouns, grammatical-number

I nomi composti, ossia i nomi che derivano dall'unione di due parole diverse (“altopiano”, “purosangue”, “grattacapo” e “caffelatte” ad esempio) sono molto comuni. Il problema con questi termini è quando si devono usare al plurale: altopiani o altipiani?
Qual è la regola per fare il plurale di un nome composto? Si devono usare al plurale entrambi i termini o, a seconda dei casi uno dei due?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esiste un ottimo articolo dell'Accademia delle Crusca che spiega come formare il plurale dei nomi composti.

Puoi trovarlo qui: [Plurale Nomi Composti](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/plurale-alcuni-nomi-composti).

La regola generale è mutare la desinenza del sostantivo.

Es. verbo + nome singolare maschile => `il grattacapo` diventa `i grattacapi`

Es. verbo + nome singolare femminile => `l'asciugamano` diventa `gli asciugamani`

**Esistono, tuttavia, delle eccezioni.**

L'articolo, per fare un esempio, parla dei nomi composti con la parola "capo".

Riguardo alle parole che hai citato...

`l'altopiano` => `gli altipiani` o `gli altopiani` (secondo Treccani ambedue sono accettabili, ma la prima forma è la più usata nella lingua parlata)

`il purosangue` => `i purosangue`

`il grattacapo` => `i grattacapi` (citato nell'articolo)

`il caffellatte` => `i caffellatte`

Spero di esserti stato d'aiuto.